# Designing NoSQL Data Model and Storage System

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, nosql, hbase

I have got a problem scenario like below:

The XYZ website need to show a page with list of all the recipes and when user clicks on each of the recipe they want to show the Recipe page with their ingredients. They also want user to further click into each of the ingredient and see all the recipes linked to that ingredients.

Currently, recipes data is received as feeds from legacy system in a form of a CSV. CSV data looks like this

recipe_id,recipe_name, description, ingredient, active, updated_date, created_date

1, pasta, Italian pasta, tomato sauce, true, 2018-01-09 10:00:57,  2018-01-10 13:00:57
1, pasta, null, cheese, true, 2018-01-09 10:10:57,  2018-01-10 13:00:57
2, lasagna, layered lasagna, cheese, true, 2018-01-09 10:00:57,  2018-01-10 13:00:57
2, lasagna, layered lasagna, blue cheese, false, 2018-01-09 10:00:57,  2018-01-10 13:00:57  ….

```
    Assume that this CSV is consume every 1 hour with 1TB of data You are asked to:
```

1. Create a data model which can store this data to allow user to do the 
   activities mentioned above. This data model needs to support millions of 
   read per second.
2. Discuss the persistence system you are going to use to store this data.
3. Write a Spark Job in Scala which can takes the CSV shown above and store 
   that in the storage system of your choice using the data model you discussed 
   above.
4. Write queries to answer the following 
   a.  Average number of recipes which are updated per hour
       i. Eg. Pasta got updated twice in one hour
   b.  Number of recipes which got updated at 10:00 clock in the entire year.

My question is,
which storage system (HBASE,Cassandra, Redis etc.,) best suits for this scenario ?
Any datamodel help will be appreciated.

Many Thanks,
Kavi

Answer (score 0):

Redis is an in-memory database, which means you'll need at least > 1TB of RAM to store your dataset. This is not cheap and may be overkill for your use case.

Cassandra is a good choice for the simple key-value, read heavy workload you describe.

```
CREATE TABLE recipe ( 
    id int PRIMARY KEY, 
    name text, 
    description text,
    ingredients list <text>, 
    active boolean,
    updated_date timestamp, 
    created_date timestamp
);
```